# Choose databits from combobox

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qcombobox, qtserialport

I have a simple GUI for serial communication with an Arduino UNO. First I list all databit in an `OrderedDict`, then I put them in a combobox:

```
self.databits = OrderedDict([
            ('5', QtSerialPort.QSerialPort.Data5),
            ('6', QtSerialPort.QSerialPort.Data6),
            ('7', QtSerialPort.QSerialPort.Data7),
            ('8', QtSerialPort.QSerialPort.Data8)
        ])
        self.databit_comboBox.addItems(list(self.databits))
```

Then I run the code, I select an option from databits combobox (this is how I get data from combobox)

```
self.serial.setDataBits(self.databit_comboBox.currentData())
```

and when I press connect button, I get this error:

```
TypeError: setDataBits(self, QSerialPort.DataBits): argument 1 has unexpected type 'NoneType'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add data with `addItems()` method you only add text, so you will discard the second part. The solution is to iterate and separate each part:

```
databits = [
        ('5', QtSerialPort.QSerialPort.Data5),
        ('6', QtSerialPort.QSerialPort.Data6),
        ('7', QtSerialPort.QSerialPort.Data7),
        ('8', QtSerialPort.QSerialPort.Data8)
]
for text, databit in databits:
    self.databit_comboBox.addItem(text, databit)

# ...

self.serial.setDataBits(self.databit_comboBox.currentData())
```

Comment: now I get this error: 
for text, databit in databits: ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Comment: @Vesa95 Are you using the same code as mine? I'm not using OrderedDict

Comment: You have right, sorry, it was my mistake, I did not notice that you removed OrderedDict. Thank you a lot @eyllanesc ! Now it's working perfect!